# How to copy from one vim instance to another using registers

Tags: vim

How can I select the `+` register? I have problems following the instructions below to copy/paste text from vim to another vim:

```
In the vim, highlight, select + register, and yank (save) to it:
Shift-v
"+y

In the second vim, select + register, and paste from it:
"+p
```

I think I'm pressing the wrong keys. When it says `"+y`, do I simply hit the keys <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> in sequence? (That is, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>). It does not work for me.

I am using Red Hat and vim in an X11 terminal. And vim version is

```
$vim --version | grep xterm_clipboard
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

Comment: Can you use gvim, instead? That is how you can use the X clipboard to transfer text using the X clipboard. Yes, you use those exact keys. Your vim doesn't have xterm_clipboard support.

Comment: yes, gvim worked!

Answer (score 6):

Vim uses the system cut-and-paste mechanism to copy text between instances. When you run vim in a terminal, it doesn't have direct access to any cut-and-paste mechanism. If vim is running in xterm or some other terminal that provides access to X selections and clipboard contents, vim can use that; however your vim binary is compiled without support for that feature.

If both vim instances are running on the same machine, you can use a temporary file to communicate:

```
:w ~/vim.tmp
:r ~/vim.tmp
```

If both vim instances are connected to the same X display (in that the `DISPLAY` environment variable points to the same X display, the vim programs themselves don't need to have any kind of X support), you can use the X selections via an external program such as [xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/) or [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/). You can omit the `p` or `-selection primary` or choose a different selection (`-s`/`secondary` or `-b`/`clipboard`). Use `:w !` (note the space) to copy:

```
:w !xsel -ip
:w !xclip -i -selection primary
```

and `:r!` to paste:

```
:r !xsel -op
:r !xclip -o -selection primary
```

Answer (score 0):

On Red Hat (and Fedora), use the `/usr/bin/vimx` command. The + register (system clipboard) will work if you use the `vimx` command.

vimx has support for the system clipboard compiled in:

```
$ vimx --version | grep xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
```

`vimx` is in the `vim-X11` package, which also contains `gvim`.

Use this alias:

```
alias vim=/usr/bin/vimx
```

Answer (score -1):

Your examples use the `+` register. To use the `?` register, simply use the same commands, replacing the `+` with `?`.

for example:

```
"?y
"?p
```

If you're trying to paste between instances of vim using the system clipboard, you'll want to prepend a `g` to your commands, thus

```
"+gy
"+gp
```

Comment: I don't think he's talking about the `?` register; the `?` was just ending a sentence that contained a question. He's using the `+` register but needs it to work between vim instances (so your part about using the system clipboard will probably solve his problem)

Comment: still not working with "+gy

Comment: `?` is not a supported register name. `"?y` does nothing