# Pasting from clipboard to vi-enabled zsh or bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, vi, clipboard

I'd like to be able to paste from the system clipboard (or text selection) into my "vi-like" shell prompt using the keyboard. I normally use zsh and sometimes bash. In both cases, I have the shell set up with vi-like behaviour (`bindkey -v` / `set -o vi`).

In vim, the behaviour I'm looking for is available with the key sequence `"+p`. This particular key sequence doesn't work as expected in a vi-enabled shell prompt, though. Is there any way to either enable this or a similar behaviour, using keyboard only, while remaining with vi-like keybindings in a zsh or bash shell prompt?

-- edit --

Usage case: I often navigate between Firefox with the [Pentadactyl addon](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/), a terminal emulator and vim itself - using the [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) window manager with custom keys to move around. All three programs have vi-like keybindings, which is very efficient (for "finger memory") so it would be ideal communicate text between them using vim syntax (or a very similar syntax) only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zsh doesn't support anything but internal registers, and bash doesn't support register at all as far as I know. By and large, shells support vi commands, not vim commands.

In zsh, here's a proof-of-concept for accessing the X selection from command mode. For real use you'd want to elaborate on these techniques. I use the `xsel` program, you can use `xclip` instead; see [How to copy from one vim instance to another using registers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13642/how-to-copy-from-one-vim-instance-to-another-using-registers/13671#13671). You'll find the features I used in the [zle manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zsh-Line-Editor).

```
vi-append-x-selection () { RBUFFER=$(xsel -o -p </dev/null)$RBUFFER; }
zle -N vi-append-x-selection
bindkey -a '^X' vi-append-x-selection
vi-yank-x-selection () { print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | xsel -i -p; }
zle -N vi-yank-x-selection
bindkey -a '^Y' vi-yank-x-selection
```

The function `vi-append-x-selection` inserts the current X selection after the cursor (similar to `p` or `P`). The function `vi-yank-x-selection` copies the last killed or yanked text to the X selection. `zle -N` declares the functions as zle widgets (i.e. edition commands). `bindkey -a` sets bindings for vi command mode.

Comment: This worked perfectly after installing `xsel` and copying your suggested code with a slight modification to my .zshrc (I chose '^P' instead of '^X', overwriting the original behaviour of '^P')

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'. I tried to implement your answer without success. I posted a question with what I tried so far: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703946/how-to-remap-the-command-buffer-of-the-clipboard-xsel-to-ctrl-v . Do you have any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution for zsh (vi mode) that wraps the original widgets so the clipboard always is synchronized

Replace `xclip` with your preferred clipboard tool.

```
function x11-clip-wrap-widgets() {
    # NB: Assume we are the first wrapper and that we only wrap native widgets
    # See zsh-autosuggestions.zsh for a more generic and more robust wrapper
    local copy_or_paste=$1
    shift

    for widget in $@; do
        # Ugh, zsh doesn't have closures
        if [[ $copy_or_paste == "copy" ]]; then
            eval "
            function _x11-clip-wrapped-$widget() {
                zle .$widget
                xclip -in -selection clipboard <<<\$CUTBUFFER
            }
            "
        else
            eval "
            function _x11-clip-wrapped-$widget() {
                CUTBUFFER=\$(xclip -out -selection clipboard)
                zle .$widget
            }
            "
        fi

        zle -N $widget _x11-clip-wrapped-$widget
    done
}


local copy_widgets=(
    vi-yank vi-yank-eol vi-delete vi-backward-kill-word vi-change-whole-line
)
local paste_widgets=(
    vi-put-{before,after}
)

# NB: can atm. only wrap native widgets
x11-clip-wrap-widgets copy $copy_widgets
x11-clip-wrap-widgets paste  $paste_widgets
```

Comment: This works like a charm in `xterm-termite`.

Comment: Seems to work great and also with `tmux`!

Answer (score 5):

There's a ZSH plugin I'd recommend: https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard . To [install](https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard#installation) it, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard ~/.zsh/plugins/zsh-system-clipboard
```

And then source the file in your `.zshrc`:

```
source "$HOME/.zsh/plugins/zsh-system-clipboard/zsh-system-clipboard.zsh"
```

---

The plugin supports [using Tmux' buffers](https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard#options) to locate where the clipboard is saved, and you can even [configure alternative keybindings](https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard#configuration) for the functions that cut / paste / copy.

One slight detail the plugin has taken care of, which the other answers suggested don't, is differentiating between system clipboard contents **with and without** new lines (see [PR](https://github.com/kutsan/zsh-system-clipboard/pull/22)). This small checks of the clipboard input, should ensure the experience of pasting any type of content is identical to that of Vim/Neovim.

Comment: I added it as a oh-my-zsh plugin, and it worked directly. Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Selection and clipboard are different things under X Window, and IMHO "desktop environments" tend to make the issue even more murky than it was.

Does shift-insert work for you? On bare X applications, it is bound to pasting the selection when such a binding is made.

Comment: Selection and clipboard being different is not really relevant here, a solution that works with one would be easy to adapt to the other. Desktop environments don't change a thing; their spread has accompanied a shift in the balance of power away from selection and towards the clipboard.

Comment: _shift-insert_ does work in my environment, and it's definitely good to know, for use when in a different system. I'm looking however for something closer to actual vim keybindings for yank and/or paste between terminals, vim itself and other programs

Answer (score 1):

*This solution works if you have installed `oh-my-zsh` and enabled the [`vi-mode`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode)  plugin.*

Gilles' `xsel` and `zle` based solution didn't work for me. However, since I have configured vim to use my system clipboard by default (`set clipboard=unnamedplus` in `~/.vimrc`), I simply type <kbd>v</kbd> in terminal normal mode to open the current command in `vim` and then I can copy it to the X-clipboard with any of the `vim` yank commands.

Comment: How is this related to ZSH? Are you talking about the embedded `:term` available in the new versions of Neovim and Vim?

Comment: @DoronBehar If you have vi-mode enabled in zsh, you can type `v` in normal mode to edit the currently typed command inside vim instead of at the terminal prompt.

Comment: You should mention the fact that you are talking about Neovim's and Vim's `:term` feature in your answer, otherwise it's not clear at all.

Comment: @DoronBehar I am not talking about `:term`. However, I did discover that the [functionality I am referring to](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode) is actually provided by `oh-my-zsh`. I have updated the answer accordingly.