# zsh copy and paste like emacs

Tags: zsh, clipboard

I have noticed that zsh has a lot of things I see in emacs. I can make a selection with ctrl+space and selecting a region. I can make copies just like in emacs while I stay inside zsh. In emacs I'm able to use my system clipboard (previously with some additional configuration needed but this works out of the box now in emacs). In zsh I can't seem to paste from my clipboard using C-y and copying from zsh to my system cliipboard has the same issue. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 15):

Zsh's has a built-in clipboard that doesn't communicate with other applications. Since it's very scriptable, you can make it communicate with a few lines in your `~/.zshrc`. You'll need [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) or [xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/). See [Pasting from clipboard to vi-enabled zsh or bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25765/pasting-from-clipboard-to-vi-enabled-zsh-or-bash-shell/25839#25839) for a proof-of-concept in vi mode. Here's the corresponding code for emacs mode (you'll probably want to do something similar to other `kill-*` widgets).

```
x-copy-region-as-kill () {
  zle copy-region-as-kill
  print -rn $CUTBUFFER | xsel -i -b
}
zle -N x-copy-region-as-kill
x-kill-region () {
  zle kill-region
  print -rn $CUTBUFFER | xsel -i -b
}
zle -N x-kill-region
x-yank () {
  CUTBUFFER=$(xsel -o -b </dev/null)
  zle yank
}
zle -N x-yank
bindkey -e '\ew' x-copy-region-as-kill
bindkey -e '^W' x-kill-region
bindkey -e '^Y' x-yank
```

This uses the X11 clipboard (typically accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>); remove the `-b` option to use the X11 primary selection instead (automatic copy on select, and paste with the middle mouse button).

Comment: If you use vi mode, simply replace `kill-region` with `vi-delete` and `yank` with `vi-put-after` etc.  Similarly wrap `vi-yank`, and others. (I haven't found a way to do it more centrally)

Comment: What is equivalent for `xsel -o -b` on `pbcopy/pbpaste` ?

Comment: @alper `xsel -o` corresponds to `pbpaste` and `xsel -i` corresponds to `pbcopy`. There's no equivalent to `-b` since macOS doesn't have multiple selections.

Comment: I tried `ctrl-k` seems like it does not copy the cutted line , is it a normal behavior?

Comment: @alper It one of the other `kill-*` widgets for which you need to write similar code.

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine but when I use them in remotely connected nodes, copy-paste operations takes few seconds, which is pretty slow, due to x11 (I believe). Is it a normal case or could it be faster ? @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'

Answer (score 5):

I had been wanting to integrate Zsh's cut buffer with the X clipboard. I tried the aforementioned http://stchaz.free.fr/mouse.zsh but I found I disliked having all my Zsh operations populate the clipboard. For instance, sometimes I would copy something in a browser, and then go to a shell and edit the command line and then paste. But often editing the command line - deleting a word, for instance - modifies the Zsh cut buffer. For better or worse, X just has a clipboard, not a kill ring, so when a Zsh editing operation overwrites the clipboard, the thing I wanted to paste is lost - I can't yank-pop it (C-y M-y) as I could do in Zsh or Emacs.

So what I did instead is create new special keybindings to interact with the X clipboard through zsh. Turns out "^Xw" and "^Xy" are unused in both Emacs and Zsh, so I can get a consistent interface by binding them in both applications. This way the normal editing operations, cutbuffer, and kill ring are left alone. If I want to copy something to the clipboard I set the region and do "^Xw" (or if I've already killed it and the region is inactive I can just do "^Xw" to copy the cut buffer). Pasting from the clipboard is done with "^Xy".

```
# define commands to copy and paste x clipboard

# ^Xw - copy region, or cut buffer
# ^Xy - paste x clipboard

# in both cases, modifies CUTBUFFER

copy-to-xclip() {
    [[ "$REGION_ACTIVE" -ne 0 ]] && zle copy-region-as-kill
    print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | xclip -selection clipboard -i
}

zle -N copy-to-xclip
bindkey "^Xw" copy-to-xclip

paste-xclip() {
    killring=("$CUTBUFFER" "${(@)killring[1,-2]}")
    CUTBUFFER=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
    zle yank
}

zle -N paste-xclip
bindkey "^Xy" paste-xclip
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at http://stchaz.free.fr/mouse.zsh which in addition to add mouse support also tries to interact with the X Clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS users: here is how to make ESC-w (a.k.a. Meta-w or Option-w) copy to the macOS pasteboard as well as the zsh built-in clipboard.

```bsh
pb-copy-region-as-kill () {
  zle copy-region-as-kill
  print -rn $CUTBUFFER | pbcopy
}
zle -N pb-copy-region-as-kill
bindkey -e '\ew' pb-copy-region-as-kill
```

For completeness: here is code for Ctrl-u and Ctrl-k too

```bsh
pb-backward-kill-line () {
  zle backward-kill-line
  print -rn $CUTBUFFER | pbcopy
}
zle -N pb-backward-kill-line
bindkey -e '^u' pb-backward-kill-line
pb-kill-line () {
  zle kill-line
  print -rn $CUTBUFFER | pbcopy
}
zle -N pb-kill-line
bindkey -e '^k' pb-kill-line
```