# How to paste selection from vi-mode to clipboard

Tags: zsh, clipboard, vi-mode, xclip, xsel

I want to access the content of what I copied in the buffer with the vi-mode of the clipboard via the command `ctrl` + `v` or `ctrl` + `shift` + `v` in the terminal.

I copied in my .zshrc the following: (from this answer:
[Pasting from clipboard to vi-enabled zsh or bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25765/pasting-from-clipboard-to-vi-enabled-zsh-or-bash-shell))

```
vi-append-x-selection () { RBUFFER=$(xsel -o -p </dev/null)$RBUFFER; }
zle -N vi-append-x-selection
bindkey -a '^X' vi-append-x-selection
vi-yank-x-selection () { print -rn -- $CUTBUFFER | xsel -i -p; }
zle -N vi-yank-x-selection
bindkey -a '^Y' vi-yank-x-selection
```

When I highlight something in the terminal in vi-mode and yank it, I can successfully retrieve it by typing `Ctrl` + `shift` + `y`. However when I type `Ctrl` + `shift` + `v`, something else in being pasted.

When I inspect the content of the clipboard with the following commands:

```
xclip -o sel p
xclip -o sel s
xclip -o sel c
xsel -o -p
xsel -o -s
xsel -o -b
```

it contains other string that I peviously copied with other means but NOT what I highlighted in vi-mode.

Here is my **first question**: if I can retrieve it with the command `Ctrl` + `shift` + `y` and confirm that with `xsel` and `xclip` that it is not in one of the three buffer ("primary", "secondary" and "clipboard") where is stored then???)

I also tried to replace the '^Y' by '^V' in the line

```
bindkey -a '^Y' vi-yank-x-selection
```

(as follows:)

```
bindkey -a '^V' vi-yank-x-selection
```

Without any success (it seems to print out an empty buffer)

**my second question**: What am I doing wrong?